# why is my try- except block stuck in the loop?

Tags: python, try-except

I am trying to catch an Index out of range error with the following try and except block.

```
def getStepList(r, h, d):
    x = len(r)-1
    y = len(h)-1
    list = []
    while True:
        try:
            if x == 0 and y == 0: 
                break
            elif x >= 1 and y >= 1 and d[x][y] == d[x-1][y-1] and r[x-1] == h[y-1]:
                x = x - 1
                y = y - 1
            elif y >= 1 and d[x][y] == d[x][y-1]+1:
                #insertion
                x = x
                y = y - 1
                list.append(h[y])
                print('insertion')

            elif x >= 1 and y >= 1 and d[x][y] == d[x-1][y-1]+1:
                #substitution
                x = x - 1
                y = y - 1
                list.append(r[x])
                print('substitution')

            else:
                #deletion
                x = x - 1
                y = y
                list.append(r[x])
                print('deletion')

        except IndexError:
            print('index error')

    return list[::-1]
```

but it gets stuck in a infinite loop. I want it to ignore it and proceed appending the next instances. (For reference its a piece of code that uses a metric of another function to determine which words were inserted, substituted or deleted at each operation).

I feel like I should know this, but in all honesty I am stuck.

Comment: If you have an `IndexError` it suggests you've reached the end of your loop. You can have `break` in `except IndexError:`

Comment: Have you printed `x` and `y` to see if they ever *both* become `0`?

Comment: Because there is no terminating condition for the loop in the exception. When it gets an exception, it moves to the the exception part and then to the next iteration of loop. You might want to put a break condition inside except part.

Comment: First, re-raise the error you catch instead of ignoring (other than to print a generic message) so that you know what's causing the error. In general, though, strive to keep as little code in a `try` block as possible, to reduce the possible sources of the expected error.

Comment: Clearly, though, the problem is indexing `d`, unless there is some unstated guarantee that the size of `d` is related to those of `r` and `h`.

Comment: The approach is fundamentally unsound. Don’t catch out of range errors. **Prevent** them by fixing your code: these errors can’t happen in a correct program. They happen because you have an error in your logic. The infinite loop is simply a symptom of this underlying problem (because, in the case of an error, you’ve provided no logic to update the indices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do a while True.  Change your while condition to:

```
while(not (x == 0 and y == 0)):
```

Inside your exception also add a break

```
except IndexError:
     print('index error')
     break
```

You could also add some checks to see what the specific Index Error might be:

```
d_len = len(d)
r_len = len(r)
h_len = len(h)
d_x_of_y_len = len(d[x][y])
if(x > d_len):
    print("x is too big")
if(y > d_x_of_y_len):
    print("y is too big")
```

Comment: Or `while x != 0 or y != 0:`

Comment: This is a good, unrelated suggestion but it fundamentally doesn’t fix OP’s problem.

Comment: btw thanks for the debugging suggestion, someone has been providing erroneous data to me, so I managed to fix that too.